# How can I generate and return a result in one expression?

Tags: c++

I have a `class` similar to this:

```
class Frac
{
    int numer;
    int denom;
public:
    Frac &simplify();

    Frac(int &&num, int &&den) : numer { num }, denom { den }
    {
        simplify();
    }

    Frac operator*(const int &rhs)
    {
        Frac result = { numer * rhs, denom };
        return result.simplify();
    }
}
```

However, I don't like using the intermediate `result` when overloading `*`.

Ideally, I'd like to do something like this:

```
Frac operator*(const int &rhs)
{
    return { numer * rhs, denom }.simplify();
}
```

but that doesn't work; it constructs an `std::initializer_list<int>` instead of a `Frac` and you can't call the member function. In C I would be able to do this with a compound literal but those are not available in standard C++.

How can I generate and return a result in one expression?

Comment: What is the type signature for `simplify` and what do your constructors look like?

Comment: @Skam Take a look.

Comment: ... { simplify(); } has no lhs ?

Comment: @nonock `simplify` modifies the values but I return `*this` to simplify (no pun intended) returning the fraction and simplifying it at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are already calling `simplify()` in the constructor, all you need to call is the constructor by itself, and return the object it creates:

```cpp
Frac operator*(const int &rhs)
{
    return Frac(numer * rhs, denom);
}
```

If you decide later on to update the constructor to no longer call `simplify()`, you can still call `simplify()` explicitly on the object that is created by calling the constructor:

```cpp
Frac operator*(const int &rhs)
{
    return Frac(numer * rhs, denom).simplify();
}
```

Comment: @S.S.Anne do you need the rvalue references? They just seem to be a complication here.

Comment: @user4581301 This is an oversimplification of a rather complex template, although I suppose I don't. I'll change that.

Comment: @S.S.Anne Just wanted to check. Sometimes I overkill for "uhhhhh... I ... No. I guess I don't"'s sake.